# Replicate div image as site's background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, gallery

I've been using a slider to show four different gallery slides, one after the other, fading in and out. I want to replicate the slide image (whichever one is showing inside the slider) as the site's main background image at the same time. Is this possible and if it is, would someone be kind enough to show me a working example? When the slider changes to slide2.jpg, for example, the body background changes to a blown up version of slide2.jpg, and so on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can post  `html` , `css` , `js` ?

Answer (score 0):

Can I assume you already know how to get the URL of the image that is showing?

```
var newBackgroundImage = $(...).prop("src");
$("body").css("background-image",newBackgroundImage);
```

Comment: Best to treat me like an absolute beginner, Paul. I'm hopeless at this sort of thing, to be honest. That's why I ask on here. All I know is that the slider will scroll through 4 images and will change when you click left or right. I'm just learning as I go.

Comment: Regrettably, there's no "general purpose" way to find the image currently being shown on a random carousel image viewer.  You'll have to post the details of your specific implementation to get better answers here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough question to answer without implementation-specific details, however, you could do something like this:

```
$(document).on('slide', '#slider', function(target) {
    var image = $(target).css('background-image');
    $('body').css('background-image', image);
});
```

Then, somehow hook into the slider's actual slide event:

```
 $(document).trigger('slide', $('#slider'));
```

This is pseudo-code, but hopefully this will help you along. Good luck!